# How to perform comparison operation for Django FloatField/DecimalField

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

This is my model.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserModel, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    usn = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=False, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=False)
    contact_no = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=False)
    tenth = models.FloatField(default=0)
    twelfth = models.FloatField(default=0)
    cgpa = models.FloatField(default=0)
    backlog = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    active_backlog = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    branch = models.ForeignKey(Branches, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    pc = models.ForeignKey(PC, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name
```

I am not able to filter the following query.

```
Student.objects.filter(tenth__gt='some decimal value')
```

Example

```
Student.objects.filter(tenth__gt=10.0)
```

And it throws an Error

```
decimal.InvalidOperation: [<class 'decimal.InvalidOperation'>]
```

It works with `IntegerField` but not with `FloatField` or `DecimalField`

Comment: I do not get a problem with `FloatField` or `DecimalField`.

Comment: Any suggestions on why it might not be working.

Comment: are you sure you did *not* overwrite the attributes with a *decimal* instead of a `DecimalField`?

Comment: There is no typo error in the code.

Comment: not per se a typo. Perhaps something like `Student.tenth = 12.34`.

Comment: `student = Student.objects.filter(tenth__gt=10.0)` works. But when tried to iterate `student` it fails with the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Student.objects.filter(tenth=some decimal value without quotes)
```

Comment: I am using without quotes and works for `=` but not for gte gt lte or lte